# Git "manual merge" strategy

Tags: git, merge

I have two branches in which the project is working at both tips.

I merge Branch A into Branch B (`git checkout BranchB; git merge BranchA`), resolve conflicts, and test Branch B to find that it no longer works.

I'm pretty sure the problem is being caused by just one or two commits from Branch A that git is prioritizing above Branch B. Therefore, I'm looking for a way to merge in which "auto-merges" don't take place, so that I can bring to bear a fine degree of control over how conflict resolution takes place. Is this possible?

Comment: Have you read the chapter on merge strategies in the manual (`git help merge`)? Maybe another strategy or an options (such as `patience`) will help..

Comment: You could also interactively rebase the changes made in BranchB onto BranchA. Specify "edit" for every commit. Then git will stop after applying each commit, giving you a chance to test and modify it.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure about skipping merging all together, but you can use

git merge --no-commit

This will allow you to perform the merge, then inspect the merged files before they're committed.

Answer (score 0):

I think that the best solution would be to rebase Branch A on branch B instead of merging.
I this case each commit that you have conflicts on would require your manual intervention and you can effectively resolve it the way it supposed to be.

After the rebase of branch A on branch B the merge of branch A to branch B will result in a simple fast-forward

so:

```
git checkout branchA
git rebase branchB
```

resolve conflict on a commit

```
git add file_with_conflicts
git rebase --continue
```

Answer (score 0):

This seems like it calls for [git-imerge](https://github.com/mhagger/git-imerge).  Which I admit I have never used, but it would give you the ability to do tests on "intermediate" merges, or on the individual commits in a "rebase-with-history" style merge.